# DB2 Current Schema replaced on the fly

Tags: java, db2, mybatis, netflix-eureka

hope you can help me with an weird issue I'm facing in a project.

I'm running over a Java app that is currently running with Eureka, MyBatis, DB2 as database & Druid datasource.

We have a DB2 URI to configure the database connection, in that one, we are setting up the currentSchema:

```
jdbc:db2://localhost:8081/MYDB:currentSchema=MYSCHEMA;charSet=UNICODE;
```

As you can see in the before URI connection, we are passing directly the currentSchema in which we wants to work.

In addition, we are passing the username & password as spring properties due we are using Druid Datasource:

```
spring.datasource.username=MYUSERNAME
spring.datasource.password=MYPASSWORD
```

When I deploy the app, everything runs correctly, the database connects to `MYSCHEMA.AnyDBTable`, however, by any reason that really I'm not understanding, some times, by any reason, the currentSchema, is replaced with the username `MYUSERNAME.AnyDBTable`, we have been spending time trying to figure out why is happening that, we have reviewed our code a lot of times trying to see if, in any place our code is doing the replace, however we are sure that is not happening from our code.

As you could figure out, that causes issues when trying to get info from DB because `MYUSERNAME.AnyDBTable` does not exist.

we are using the below dependency in our project for DB2:

```
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.db2:jcc:jar:11.5.5.0:compile
```

Any idea guys why could be happening that?, any help will be well received.

**NOTE**: we validated the .properties files living on eureka server, and the currentSchema is not modified, it is as we defined it initially, after reseting the whole app, it works correctly again.

Comment: When the schema-name is incorrect,  it the incorrect value the same as the username  OR a valid username ?  At any time, are connections closed and reconnected (with the reconnecting code not setting the currentSchema special register?).

Comment: are there any trigger in your tables ?

Comment: @mao yes, when the queries start failing is because the incorrect currentSchema value is the same than our userName, and yes, the userName is a valid value, is the one we use to conect to the db2 db, really we dont have a code for reconnect with the db, its the default config for Druid Datasource.

Comment: @mshbou no, we really dont have triggers in our tables.

Comment: You might not have code to re-connect if the connection drops (due to some event outside your control) , __but__ some code in a library that you use may have reconnect logic. Or there can be a flaw in connection-pooling.  If you have a reproducible scenario (emphasis, reproducible), then tracing of jdbc will indicate the problem.

Comment: @Telluz21 If you use WebSphere Application Server, be sure to set [`usingCustomSchemaName`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/nd?topic=configuration-httpsessiondatabase) to `true`. If that is not the case, I would try replacing Druid with HikariCP and see if there is any change (mainly because it is relatively easy to try).

Comment: Haven't happened to me in WebSphere/DB2 but I remember years back one thread was changing the current schema at runtime (for a specific query). Now, since the app server used a connection pool, the same connection was later reused by another thread that assumed it was still in the initial schema... and boom! It was a matter of hunting down that rogue query and problem solved.

Comment: In did it's courious because it have happening the same thing, and both times, have been when the db2 service is facing issues and it's unavailable.